# django, views direct to a another html page

Tags: django

I am using Django for develop a website. The website is intended to use to search information stored in a MySQL database.

This is the current basic flow of the web site.
1) index.html - this has a form to select an option
2) according the option, users will redirect to search.html (include a form)
3) once the user provides the criteria, the result will be displayed in reply.html

In my views.py , I have two functions.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from website.models import WebsiteRepository
from .forms import SearchForm
from .forms import SelectTypeForm


def Search(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    #do something
    return render(request, 'reply.html', {'env_dict':env_dict})
else:
    #do something
    return render(request, 'search.html', context = context)

def index(request):

if request.method =='POST':
   #do something
   return render(request, 'search.html', context = context) 
else:
    #do something
    return render(request, 'index.html', context= context)
```

When I go to index.html page, I can select a option and it will direct me to search.html. After, I fill the form there and submit, it wont give me the reply.html page.

I have a feeling that, I could make this work by changing urls.py.

```
from django.urls import path
from website import views


 urlpatterns = [
      path('', views.index, name='index'),
      #path('search/', view.Search, name ='Search')

 ]
```

I tried to google it. But its too much details and Iam kind of lost.

Do any of you guys know how to achieve this?

Thanks

search.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}

   <h3>Welcome to search information Repository</h3>
   <form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button type = 'submit'>submit</button>
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% block content %}
   <h3>Welcome to information Repository</h3>
       <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{form.as_p}}
    <button type = 'submit'>submit</button>
  </form>
```

just for clarify things more, ill add the forms.py too

```
from django import forms
from .models import  WebsiteRepository

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   websiterepository = WebsiteRepository


   env_indicators =  websiterepository.objects.filter (key_aspect='Environmental').values_list('repo_id','indicator')
   indicator = forms.ChoiceField(choices=env_indicators,label = 'Indicator'      )


  OPTIONS = (('2000','2000'),('2001','2001'),('2002','2002'), ('2003','2003'),('0000','0000'),)
   year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTIONS)





class SelectTypeForm(forms.Form): 

      OPTIONS = (('1', 'Envirnmental Indicators'),('2','Economic Indicators'),('3','Social Indicators'),)
      types = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTIONS)
```

Comment: Please provide `search.html` and `index.html` code.

Comment: Your form request seems to be post that's why it not redirecting to index.

Comment: @Sasha this is your index.html?

Comment: After filling the form if you don't see result.html what exactly do you see. Also for search GET should be used, POST is used when creating, updating database entries. See usage [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Hi guys,I added the search html file.

Comment: Are you sure you are redirecting to search.html and not posting on index.html. Check if your url is changing. Also what is right now you are getting?

Comment: @aquaman, no,  url is not changing.once i hit the submit button in index.html, will go to search.html. when i hit the submit button there, it will stay in search.html. In the server side, it shows it is getting 'post' requests

Comment: Check in your search function what django thinks `request.method` is.  Just print it out or something.

Comment: @Vaibhav Vishal. Do you think I should use a get request instead of post in index.html and search.html ?

Comment: Yes as long as it doesn't changes anything in the database. It's not required POST will work too, but it's convention to use POST to create/update objects while GET to fetch objects.

Comment: In urls uncomment the second url, In views -> index view's post instead of rendering search.html redirect to `Search`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal why redirect at all when you can just point the form to the search view ?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I know when and why to use POST and GET, thanks - what I meant is that submitting the form to the `index` view just to redirect to the  `search` view is a WTF, the proper solution is of course to submit the form directly to the search view.

Comment: ok, i got what you are saying. And yeah that's right. I misunderstood your answer a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong on many points.

First thing first: for a search, you want a GET request, not a POST (POST is for updating the server's state - adding or updating your database mostly). This is the semantically correct method (since you want to GET data), and it will allow a user to bookmark the url.

Second point: you don't want to submit the search form to the index view but to the search view. No need for redirects etc, just use the `{% url %}` templatetag to fill the `action` attribute of your form (you of course need to have a 'Search' url in your urls.py):

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'Search' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button type = 'submit'>submit</button>
  </form>
```

if you want to have this form on more than one page (which is often the case for search forms), [use an inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) tha will take care of creating an unbound SearchForm and render the template fragment.

Then in your search view, you only want GET requests, and do not use two different templates, this will only lead to useless duplication.

```
def Search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    # use the form's data - if any - to get search results 
    # and put those results (even if empty) in you context 
    return render(request, 'reply.html', {'env_dict':env_dict})
```

And finally, your search form is totally broken:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   # this is totally useless
   websiterepository = WebsiteRepository

   # this will only be evaluated once at process startup, so you will
   # get stale data in production - and probably different data
   # per process, in a totally unpredictable way.
   # You need to either put this in the form's __init__ or wrap it
   # in a callable and pass this callable

   env_indicators =  websiterepository.objects.filter (key_aspect='Environmental').values_list('repo_id','indicator')
   indicator = forms.ChoiceField(choices=env_indicators,label = 'Indicator'      )



  # are you going to manually add a new year choice every year ???
  OPTIONS = (('2000','2000'),('2001','2001'),('2002','2002'), ('2003','2003'),('0000','0000'),)
   year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OPTIONS)
```

For the "indicators" ChoiceField you want something like:

```
def get_indicators_choices():
    return Websiterepository.objects.filter (key_aspect='Environmental').values_list('repo_id','indicator')

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
   # IMPORTANT  : we are NOT calling the function here, just
   # passing it (python functions are objects) to the field, which
   # will call it everytime the form is instanciated, so you don't
   # have stale data
   indicator = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=get_indicator_choices, 
        label='Indicator')
```

As a last note: be consistent with your namings (ie why name one view in all lower (`index`) and capitalize the other (`Search`) ? Whichever convention you choose (I strongly suggest [respecting pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) here), at least stick to it for the whole project.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I m very new to Django, yet alone to Python. Thanks for  mentioning the issues in my code and solutions also.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that code is not redirecting to `/search`, instead rendering **search.html** after post from **index.html**.

Try doing like-

views.py-

```
#your code 

def index(request):
   #do something
   if request.method == 'POST':
      return redirect('Search')
   else:
      #render index.html

def search(request):
   #do something
   if request.method == 'POST':
      #render reply.html
   else:
      #render search.html
```

Another way to achieve this is if you specify *action* in your form so that form posts on `/search`.

search.html

```
<form method="post" action="/search">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button type = 'submit'>submit</button>
   </form>
```

Comment: Hi aquaman, Thanks for the help. The first option worked for me. Additionally , I add this to  [ path('search/', views.Search, name ='Search') ] to urlpatterns in urls.py. I mentioned it here so it will be useful for someone else like me. Thanks again

Comment: If that worked, please accept it. It can be helpful for others also. Cheers.

Comment: The first solution is wrong - redirecting on a POST request will loose all the request's POST data - and the second is wrong to by hardcoding the url instead of using the ``{% url %}` templatetag.